# How does Xcode "Development" Distribution method work?

Tags: ios, xcode

How does this work?
[image: Xcode Development Distribution option]

Apple docs either seem to skip this one or have an [exact copy-paste of the **Ad Hoc** description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-your-app-for-beta-testing-and-releases#Create-a-custom-distribution) — so what is different to justify this extra option?

I would have just done it to see what happens, but it requires different signing of my app.  Xcode 14.3.